# Does Eigen sparse boolean matrix stores nonzero values?

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

Does Eigen3 sparse boolean matrix store the value of the boolean?
If that is the case, the nonzero entries are all 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and there is currently no special optimization for boolean scalar type. For instance, one can explicitly store an entry equals to `false`, just like one can insert explicit zeros within a `SparseMatrix<double>`.